# Add a cron job command into a comment without closing the comment prematurely - PHP, Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got the following comment in my code: `/* Don't forget this */`

I need to add a cron job command as a reference `*/3 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -q -O - 'https://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron' >/dev/null 2>&1` into this comment.

So Ideally I need something like this: `/* Don't forget this cron: */3 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -q -O - 'https://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron' >/dev/null 2>&1 */`

But the issue is that the first part of the cron job command where it starts as `*/` basically closes my comment prematurely.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Use `//` instead? `// Don't forget this` on one line, `// */3 * * * * /usr/bin/wget ...` on the next? That should convey the meaning to every developer who can put two and two together, I think. (And if not, add a third line explaining that the `//` aren't part of what they need to copy&paste.)

Comment: Just escape the slashes after `*`. A more elegant solution would be to put the cron inside a file and reference the file or to use `//` as comment or, better, to try some automation

Comment: @DonCallisto _"A more elegant solution would be to put the cron inside a file and reference the file or, better, to try some automation"_ - I don't think they are trying to actually set up a cron here, this is just supposed to be _documentation_ inside a PHP file.

Comment: @CBroe I know, I was suggesting to insert the file name inside the comment instead of the command as it is.

Comment: using `//` will do, thanks @CBroe